# how to set cookies manually for user sign in form in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i am new to ruby on rails plz help me to this task. I want to implement cookies in this code while sign in in a simple way. 
  here is my code......

```
  controllers:
  users controller:

        class UsersController < ApplicationController
          before_filter :authenticate_user, :except => [:index, :login,:update, :new,:create ,:logout,:login_again, :forgot_password ,:password]
          before_filter :save_login_state, :only => [:index, :login  ]
          before_filter :save_login_state, :only => [:new, :create ] 

          def new
            @user=User.new
          end

          def index   
            @user=User.new
          end

          def login
             email = params[:user][:email]
             puts params[:user][:password]
             params_pass = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(params[:user][:password])  
          if @user=User.find_by_email_and_password(email,params_pass)
                  session[:user_id] = @user.id
                  redirect_to :controller=>'users', :action=>'show' , :id=>@user.id
          else
               flash[:notice] = 'email or password is invalid....!!' 
                @user=User.new
                render "index"
          end
          end  

          def edit
             if session[:user_id]
               params[:id] = session[:user_id]
             end
               @user = User.find(params[:id])
          end

          def update
             if session[:user_id]
               params[:id] = session[:user_id]
             end
               @user= User.find(params[:id])
               @user.update_attributes(:name=>params[:user][:name], :email=>params[:user][:email],:password=>Digest::MD5::hexdigest(params[:user][:password]))
           redirect_to :controller=>'users',:action=>'show'
          end

          def show
            if session[:user_id]
              params[:id] = session[:user_id]
            end 
            @user=User.find(params[:id])
          end

          def create
              m1=Digest::MD5::hexdigest(params[:user][:password])
             if(params[:user][:password]=="")       
               flash[:password]="[password cant be blank]"
             end
              user.save 
              @user= User.new(:name=>params[:user][:name], :email=>params[:user][:email],:password=>m1)
             if  params[:user][:password] == params[:user][:password_confirmation]
                if @user.save
                  UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
                  session[:user_id]=@user.id
                  cookies[:user_email]=@user.email
                  redirect_to :controller=> 'users', :action=>'show', :id=>@user.id
                else
                  render "new"
                end
             else
                 flash[:error] = "[password did not match!]"
                 render "new"
             end
            end

           def logout
             session[:user_id] = nil
             cookies.delete(:user_email)
             redirect_to :action => 'index'
           end

           def forgot_password
             @user = User.new
           end

          def password
            @user = User.new
            email = params[:user][:email]
            @user= User.find_by_email(email)
          if @user
            UserMailer.password_reset(@user).deliver
            flash[:notice] = 'Password instructions have been mailed to you. Please check your inbox.'
           render "forgot_password"
          else
             @user = User.new
             flash[:notice] = 'email is invalid....!!'
             render "forgot_password"
          end 
          end
         end


        application controller:

        class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
           helper :all
           protect_from_forgery
           protected

            def authenticate_user
              unless session[:user_id]
              redirect_to(:controller => 'users', :action => 'index')            
              return false
            else
              @current_user = User.find session[:user_id] 
              return true
            end
            end

          def save_login_state
            if session[:user_id]
               redirect_to(:controller => 'users', :action => 'show')
               return false
            else
               return true
            end
          end
        end
```

here is the view section:

index.html.erb:

```
        <h1>WELCOME USER..........!!! </h1>

        <h1>Sign in</h1>


        <%= form_for @user, :url =>  users_login_path, :method => :post do |f| %>
          <p>
            <%= f.label 'username or email:' %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :email %>
          </p>
          <p>
            <%= f.label 'password:' %><br />
            <%= f.password_field :password %>
          </p>
          <p>
            <%= f.submit 'Sign In' %>
            <%= f.submit 'Clear Form', :type => 'reset' %>
          </p>
          <%= flash[:blank] %>
          <br>
          <br>
          <%= flash[:notice] %>
          <%=link_to link %> 

        <% end %>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>
          <%=link_to'forgot your password?',:controller=>'users', :action=>'forgot_password' %>
        </p>
            <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", :controller=>'users',:action=>'new' %>`enter code here`</p>
```

now i don't know how to use or implement cookies i hav tried in above code but it does not work.please also explain me the need and how to implement cookies without using any gems

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you give us more details on what 'id does not work' means?

Comment: i want to just ask how we set cookies in simple way and i have tried but cookies are not working what changes or addition i needed to do in this

Answer (score 4):

You Can set in the following way

```
def sign_in(user)

    # after sign in the cookie store the remember token as user.id and user.salt
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]    

    # Now the current user is that user who has signed in
    current_user = user
end
```

Comment: sorry bt i knw its easy bt i am vry new to ruby....so plz help me with the following 
    
    here i have not provided the model plz hav a look:
now look that i have not used user.salt and remember.token should i have to add these fields in the database

Comment: I would return current_user as a seperate method so you can use decorators easily. just a thought though +1

Comment: @user2996042 if you are using device for registration then you need not have to add else you should have those fields.

Comment: @user2996042 you can check this documentation too http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html